# Link random generated values to list Objects

Tags: c#, arrays, list, colors, static

I am using the following code to generate a random color.

```
static Color[] colors = { Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Yellow}; 
static Color GetRandomColor()
{
    var random = new Random();
    return colors[random.Next(colors.Length)];
}
```

Now I need to associate to a list of users:

```
        List<Utente> ListaUtente = new List<Utente>();
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(22, "Pedro", 555444333, "pedro@gmail.com"));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(22, "Lucas", 555444333, "lucas91@gmail.com"));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(22, "Rodrigo", 555444333, "rodrigo00@gmail.com"));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(22, "Gaspar", 555444333, "gaspar@gmail.com"));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(22, "Assis", 555444333, "assis@gmail.com"));
```

And display it on screen like: User 1 - Red, 
                               User 2 - Green, etc.

What's the easiest way to do this? Im not sure how can I connect these two blocks of code. Just to give you some background Im doing an Hospital managment service and I need to assign an emergency color to each of this users.

Comment: Is this winforms, WPF, ASP.NET, console...?

Comment: Add a color property to `Utente`?

Comment: Make a `List<Tuple<Color, Utente>>` rather than a `List<Utente>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
public class Colours
{
    public string ColourName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Person> People = new List<Person>()
        {
           new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Dave" },
           new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Joe" },
           new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Stephen"},
           new Person { Id = 4, Name = "Sue" },
           new Person { Id = 5, Name = "Jemma" },
           new Person { Id = 6, Name = "Sharon" },
        };
        Dictionary<int, Colours> Colours = new Dictionary<int, Colours>()
        {
            { 1, new Colours { ColourName = "Color.Red" }},
            { 2, new Colours { ColourName = "Color.Green"}},
            { 3, new Colours { ColourName = "Color.Blue"}},
        };

        Random RandomNumber = new Random();

        int ListPostionToRemoveAt = RandomNumber.Next(1, People.Count);
        int RandomColourPostion = RandomNumber.Next(1, Colours.Count);

        Person p = People[ListPostionToRemoveAt];

        Colours ColourToAssign = Colours[RandomColourPostion] ;
        p.Color = ColourToAssign.ColourName;
        Console.Write("Persons Name: " + p.Name +" Persons Colour:"+ p.Color);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically use a dictionary to store your colours as it makes linking them up to a user so much smoother.  You can extend this pretty easily, add a foreach loop in to iterate through the list, removing used elements/People to ensure you dont duplicate.

If you need any more guidance just ask.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try this now and will give you feedback later!

Comment: So from my understating, this code doesn't require the previous code I posted right? Also where you have Person, I replace it with "Utente" right?

Comment: yes Person is Utente, also remember that the List of colours is only the name of the the colours. To change just change the type in the Person class (Colour) and  int the Colour class  (ColourName) and it should output a colour attached to the person (remember to strinify that if you want to view the association as a string in the console)

Comment: Why do I need a colour Id there?

Comment: You dont, that is actually probably bad practice for larger programs. I did it because i usually associate dictionarys with selectlists in asp.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your help. So, can I remove the color generator code I posted and just use this one?

Comment: yes, but this only attaches 1 random colour to 1 random user. You would need to iterate through the list using a foreach loop, remove then add user to a new list to avoid duplication and then you will have a full list of people with associated colours.